# How can get firebase real time database usnig android studio java

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[{
"name": "Style Shoes",
"id": "123",
"image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecomfirebase-39a63.appspot.com/o/1886_side.jpeg?alt=media&token=c040a1e3-e05d-457a-ac67-dbb77934ba5d",
"size": 6,
"price": 409.45

}, {
"name": "Google Assitences",
"id": "124",
"image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecomfirebase-39a63.appspot.com/o/5fca8733bdb90c520c4127a2_EN_Google_Blog_Visual_NEW_EN.jpg?alt=media&token=087c1e24-31a0-4fba-bb5a-022d7e6800db",
"size": 0,
"price": 5499.45

}]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to retrieve data from firebase real time database for that you need to create a function and a adapter to pass data read this documentation [read this and follow the following code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).